# How to clip a UIView with a bezier path?

Tags: ios, uibezierpath

I'm not totally sure to understand how `UIBezierPath` is supposed to work.

I have added a simple `UIView` in the middle of the screen, and I wanted to clip it by adding a mask to its layer. I tried this, thinking I'd get something like a losange in the middle of the view:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    viewToClip.backgroundColor = .white
    let bezierPath = UIBezierPath()
    bezierPath.move(to: viewToClip.center)
    bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: viewToClip.center.x - 5, y: viewToClip.center.y))
    bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: viewToClip.center.x, y: viewToClip.center.y - 5))
    bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: viewToClip.center.x + 5, y: viewToClip.center.y))
    bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: viewToClip.center.x, y: viewToClip.center.y + 5))
    bezierPath.close()
    let testLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    testLayer.path = bezierPath.cgPath
    viewToClip.layer.mask = testLayer
}
```

But instead of that, the view simply disappears from the screen. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is the `backgroundColor` of your view controller's `view` different from white?

Comment: @beyowulf Yes I've set a different one

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Can you try

```
import UIKit

class bb: UIView {

   var once:Bool = true 

     override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {

      if(once)
      {
        once = false
        self.backgroundColor = .white
        let bezierPath = UIBezierPath()
        let cen = CGPoint.init(x: self.bounds.size.width/2, y: self.bounds.size.height/2)
        bezierPath.move(to: cen)
        bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: cen.x - 5, y: cen.y))
        bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: cen.x, y: cen.y - 5))
        bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: cen.x + 5, y: cen.y))
        bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: cen.x, y: cen.y + 5))
        bezierPath.close()
        let testLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        testLayer.path = bezierPath.cgPath
        testLayer.lineWidth = 1.0

        testLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
        testLayer.fillColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
        self.layer.addSublayer(testLayer)
      }        

}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works (I replaced the `addSublayer(testLayer)` by `layer.mask = testLayer`) and I get the desired result

Comment: This answer doesn't address the original question which was about masking. Also, setting up sublayers in `drawRect` is not advised as overriding `drawRect` had performance implications and should really only be used to draw directly into view's graphic context. Additionally, `drawRect` may be called multiple times, which would cause needless layers to be added to the view's layer hierarchy. 

I'm glad this answer helped the OP, but it should be updated to reflect what the problem was and how this code corrects the issue.

Comment: putting the code inside viewDidLoad has the same performance effect as in drawRect (both are in mainQueue but run in different  phases) , besides this is a simple layer not a heavy draw task that also would be written in drawRect as most open source libraries do

Comment: My point is more that `drawRect` should only be used for drawing directly into a view's graphics context. That's not what your code is doing. It is setting up and adding `CALayer`s which can and should be done in other places. _You do not need to override this method if your view sets its content in other ways. For example, you do not need to override this method if…your view sets its content directly using the underlying layer object_ https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622529-drawrect If you want to setup layers early in a `UIView`'s lifecycle use `init` or `awakeFromNib`

Comment: what about community professional developers who add labels inside it not only a layer

Comment: They should use `init` or `awakeFromNib` which are guaranteed to be called only once early in a view's lifecycle. `drawRect` may be called more than once.(_This method is called when a view is first displayed or when an event occurs that invalidates a visible part of the view._) which might cause needless views/layers to be added the view's view/layer hierarchy. Also, it's not what `drawRect` is intended for, which drawing code. Again `drawRect` is not simply the `UIView` equivalent of `viewDidLoad`, and shouldn't be treated as such.